# Send value from a method to another in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have the following code :

```
pz.flashCall = {
    updateChest: function (value, type) { 
        console.log(result);    
    },
    gameResult : function (result, level){
        var result = result;
    }
```

The problem is how to send the variable `result` from the method `gameResult()` to `updateChest()`, I tried with `var` but no result. Can you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried `window.result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Here is the easiest and worst way to do it: a global variable.

```
// res is available globally
var res;

pz.flashCall = {
    updateChest: function (value, type) { 
       // Access global variable `res`
       console.log(res);    
    }
    ,gameResult : function (result, level){
        // Set the global variable `res`
        res = result;
    }
...
```

Another way to do it is to store the variable on the `flashCall` object. This assumes that you will always call the methods from `flashCall`, ie `flashCall.gameResult()` and `flashCall.updateChest()`

```
pz.flashCall = {
    updateChest: function (value, type) {
       // Access `flashCall.result`
       console.log(this.result);    
    }
    ,gameResult : function (result, level){
        // Set `flashCall.result`
        this.result = result;
    }
...
```

Answer (score -1):

// result - is a global variable now. You can call from anywhere

```
var result;
var  flashCall = {
    updateChest : function(p_value,p_type){
       console.log(result); 
   },
    gameResult : function(p_result,p_level){
       result = p_result;
    }
}
```

// or declare inside the class like below and call this from outside like //flashCall.result

```
var flashCall = {
    result:null,
    updateChest : function(p_value,p_type){
       console.log(this.result); 
    },
    gameResult : function(p_result,p_level){
        this.result = p_result;
    }
 }
```

Like this you can declare the variable globally

Comment: This answer would greatly benefit from proper code formatting and some explanation.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Will improve my answers